# Awesome WM - running lua rc.lua gives an error

Tags: 12.04, awesome, lua

I install awesome using sudo apt-get install awesome

I copied my rc.lua to ~/.config/awesome and ran

```
    lua rc.lua
```

I got the following error:

```
      lua: rc.lua:2: module 'awful' not found:
        no field package.preload['awful']
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/awful.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/awful/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/awful.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/awful/init.lua'
        no file './awful.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/awful.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/awful/init.lua'
        no file './awful.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/awful.so'
        no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/awful.so'
        no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/awful.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
        no file './awful.so'
     stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        rc.lua:2: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

I'm using ubuntu 12.04. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong or what is missing. 
help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do? You're not really meant to run rc.lua straight through the lua interpreter.

If you want to check whether the syntax of your rc.lua is OK then use `awesome -k -c ~/.config/rc.lua`. The error

Comment: Can you give some explanation on this? I started getting a weird error in `rc.lua` *(perhaps cuz my drive is dying)*. The only thing that comes to mind is to load some modules into interactive lua shell, and find the reason step-by-step. So why can't I do this?